# What is the Throttle Settings used for in Datapower Appliance?

Tags: ibm-datapower

In Datapower , under Administration -> Devices -> Throttle setting we have many parameters. But the description isn't clear enough on the functions it does.

Parameter :

Memory Throttle At   %*

Memory Terminate At   %*

Temp File Space Throttle At   %*

Temp File Space Terminate At   %*

XML Names Warn At   %*

Timeout   seconds*

Backlog Size*

Backlog Timeout   seconds*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Memory Throttle At %**: Block incoming transactions when free memory is less than this %.
- **Memory Terminate At %**: Restart DataPower when free memory is less than this %.
- **Temp File Space Throttle At %**: Block incoming transactions when free temp storage is less this %
- **Temp File Space Terminate At %**: Restart DataPower when free temp storage is less than this %
- **XML Names Warn At %**: DataPower has a [pool to store xml prefix, namespaces etc.](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21409683) within. At this level of free posts in the pool, warn.
- **Timeout seconds**: Restarts the DataPower when throttled for this amount of time.
- **Backlog Size**: Number of requests that are queued during throttling. If backlog is full, further requests are rejected.
- **Backlog timeout seconds**: Maximum time a request can be queued in backlog.